# Intellij & Composite Build Configuration: can I Influence the order of builds?

Tags: intellij-idea

I have a multi-module project that I've created composite builds for in Intellij IDEA Ultimate 2020.1. But when I invoke my gradle build, it doesn't seem to build the dependencies in the order I need. It's pretty random. Is there anything I can do to change that?

Comment: Check this Gradle discussion: https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-to-order-a-composite-build-with-dependson/32640/7 The [Current limitations and future plans for composite builds](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/composite_builds.html#current_limitations_and_future_work) section says that `Multiple composite builds may conflict when run in parallel, if more than one includes the same build.`

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure this addresses my question.